# Where can I download Java 6 for Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: java, google-chrome

www.screenr.com doesn't work on Chrome with Java 7. I can't use a different browser, so I need to downgrade to Java 6 I guess? I've tried doing this but I think I've removed all versions of Java from my system by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to severe security issues in the browser plugin I strongly disencourage from downgrading to an earlier java verion. Rather stick to the latest release (7u13 as of now) as version 6 is already facing its end of life.
See this, for instance:
http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Oracle-releases-emergency-patches-for-Java-1796543.html

Comment: I need to record screencasts. Screenr needs Java. I need to use Chrome. Any suggestions?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml#java%20available) the correct way is to keep the OS up to date as well as the java version. Downgrading only makes sense in few cases, if ever

Comment: Apart from having an up-to-date java plugin for the browser you might consider taking a screencast with an installed software rather than a webpage plugin. Generally, there are many proprietary and open-source solutions